Error while building on Android (class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0). (React Native)
I need to release an updated version of my app. Everything was working fine until two weeks ago when I could build it without any issues. However, yesterday when I tried to build it again, I encountered this error. I'm puzzled by what might be causing it.


I've already tried changing the JDK version installed on my machine, but it ends up breaking other things, and I still can't build it

I'm having a very similar problem with Android in react-native 0.67.4 (iOS works fine)
The app was working fine with react-native-marketingcloudsdk 8.0.0 but when I try to implement Analytics using this method MCReactModule.setAnalyticsEnabled(true) I've found that this is not available in 8.0.0 so then upgrade it to 8.1.0 and then Android builds fails with this message:

If you're not using Analytics maybe you can try to downgrade your react-native-marketingcloudsdk version to 8.0.0
